# Regular Expression based search in CFEClipse for tags not containing an attribute

Tags: regex, eclipse, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I've got a few regular expressions down pat, but am struggling within CFEclipse to nail the syntax which finds:

> all instances of the **cfquery** tag that *don't* contain the attribute **name**

I've tried

```
<cfquery [^>]*(?!(name=))[^>]*>
```

which I'd intended to trap:

> the cfquery tag, followed by any number of characters that aren't the closing **>**, **NOT** followed by the **name** attribute, followed by any number of characters that aren't the closing **>**, followed by the closing **>**.

This finds plenty of matches, the some of which **do** contain the **name** attribute and some of which don't (so it's obviously incorrect).

Can anyone hit me with a clue stick on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be using an XML parser for this, but your issue is that `[^>]*` is greedy and will match through the **name** attribute if it exists.  You need something like the following:

```
<cfquery (?![^>]*name=)[^>]*>
```

By moving the `[^>]*` into the negative lookahead you can make sure that "name=" does not exist in the string before the next `>`.

Comment: An XML parser will not work against CFML.

Ideally what he needs is a CFML parser/analyser, but this is not an easy thing to create. :(   Also, your lookahead is only acting against the first `[^>]` character, not all of them.

Comment: @Peter Boughton - My regex works fine, http://www.rubular.com/r/4O2jzXd0oO - Thanks for the comments about CFML, I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were doing, yes, it does work (although would still benefit from the word boundaries I mentioned in the second part of my answer, so `<cfquery\b(?![^>]*\bname\s*=)[^>]*>`)

Comment: Thanks F.J. That works a treat. I wish I could accept both your answer AND Peter's, as whilst the "word boundary" info (currently) goes over my head, I suspect Peter's might actually be a more "complete" answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your lookahead to act against each character until the end of the opening tag, you need to split the character class and the quantifier, like so:

```
<cfquery\b(?:(?!name=)[^>])*>
```

Note the `\b` (word boundary) instead of space - this will allow `<cfquery>` to match (whilst still blocking `<cfqueryparam...>` tags. (`\b` after an alphanumeric character ensures the next character is non-alphanumeric.)

Also worth pointing out, the `(?:`...`)` is a non-capturing group - similar to normal `(`...`)` but doesn't create a backreference since we don't need it.

Of course, there is a small possibility of this not matching correctly - if you have an attribute `notname` or you have `name = "whatever"` these will both be treated incorrectly.

To solve this, we can use a `\b` again before the name this time, and then use an optional `\s` to allow (but not require) any whitespace between the attribute name and the equals sign:

```
<cfquery\b(?:(?!\bname\s*+=)[^>])*>
```

And don't forget to make sure case-insensitive flag is enabled, if you might have tags/attributes in mixed/uppercase anywhere.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I'm sorry for the delay in coming back to this Q (it's been over a month), but do appreciate your answer, and I'll have to read up on word boundaries to fully do it justice! Cheers, Aidan.